# how to check device is not able to send SMS

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I wanted to know is it possible to check that a device can send sms or not..  if my app is installed on the ipad the sms button should hide... how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this -

```
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
       // send sms
    }
```

Comment: it will return true if device can't send sms but can imessage for example

Answer (score 2):

```
BOOL canSend = [MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking for `UIDeviceSMSCapability` in [UI Device extension categories](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension) from Erica Sadun.